# Property setter not working when attribute starts with "__"?

Tags: python, properties

I am using Python 3.8.6 and this works fine

```
class A:
    @property
    def _a(self):
        return getattr(self, '_a_', 0)

    @_a.setter
    def _a(self, value):
        self._a_ = value


a = A()
print(a._a)  # prints 0
a._a = 10
print(a._a)  # prints 10 as expected
```

This doesn't work

```
class A:
    @property
    def _a(self):
        return getattr(self, '__a', 0)

    @_a.setter
    def _a(self, value):
        self.__a = value

a = A()
print(a._a)  # prints 0
a._a = 10
print(a._a)  # prints 0 again
```

That's mind blowing! the only difference between the first and second example is that the private attribute is `__a` instead of `_a_`

Any idea why? I wasn't able to figure it out

Comment: Maybe something to do with private attributes/methods denoted by leading double underscore see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=private#private-variables

Comment: that indeed explains why. If you write an answer I will accept it as a solution. "Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name with leading underscore(s) stripped. This mangling is done without regard to the syntactic position of the identifier, as long as it occurs within the definition of a class."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to [private name mangling](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers), but it doesn't apply to the contents of string literals like the one you're passing to `getattr()`.

Fortunately the fix is simple:

```
class A:
    @property
    def _a(self):
        return getattr(self, '_A__a', 0)

    @_a.setter
    def _a(self, value):
        self.__a = value

a = A()
print(a._a)  # prints 0
a._a = 10
print(a._a)  # prints 10 now
```

Comment: I think the variant using `classname` will break for subclasses, because the setter is written in the base class so the attribute name will still be mangled to `_A__a`.

Comment: @kaya3: "break" it what sense? It uses the name of the subclass in one.

Comment: Well, if `class B(A): pass` then `b = B(); b._a = 23; print(b._a)` will print `0` because the setter writes `_A__a` but the getter tries to access `_B__a`.

Comment: @kaya3: You're right, so I removed that part of my answer.